# How do I stop my viewport from lagging so much?

Tags: faces, polycount

I made a scene with mountains, trees and a house and it was causing my viewport to lag to the point where I couldn't even preview them in material view or it would just crash, meaning I can only see in solid view. The number of faces was initially 950,000 but I managed to get it down to about 380,000 using decimate. Despite doing this It's still very laggy and I still can't preview in material or rendered view or it crashes. I'm using a MacBook 16-inch 2019.
(The File size is 112MB so  can't even leave a link for it)

Any ideas on how I can fix this?

Comment: Hello maybe it has to do with the number of vertices, can't you make some objects even lighter?

Comment: It turns out it was one object that I had which was causing it to lag. After I deleted I had 100,000 less vertices and blender could actually run smoothly. Thanks!

Comment: Great then.............................   ;)